# Why is $\int_{0}^{1}{(1+x^2)^n dx} \sim \frac{2^n}{n} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

By $a_n \sim b_n$ I mean that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$.

I don't know how to do this problem. I have tried to apply binomial theorem and I got
$$\int_{0}^{1}{(1+x^2)^n dx} = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}x^{2k}dx} = \sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1{ \binom{n}{k}x^{2k}dx} = \sum_{k=0}^n  \frac {\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}$$
But I don't know what I could do with this, nor if it is a correct approach.

Comment: Convert the limits to $(0,\infty)$ then use beta function

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{n}{k}=2^n$ however I don't know why $\sum_{k=0}^n  \frac {\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}\approx \frac{2^n}{n}$

Comment: You are talking about [asymptotic equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), not approximation. I made the necessary edit in notation.

Comment: See [this page](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1487932p8718589) on AoPS.

Comment: @quantus see my solution if it correctly answer the question

Comment: for what it's worth, this means the area bounded by $y=0, x=1, x=0, $ and $y=(1+x^2)^n$ approaches the area bounded by $y=0, x=1, $ and the tangent line to $y=(1+x^2)^n$ at $x=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=(1+x^2)/2$, so that $du=x\,dx=\sqrt{2u-1}\,dx$. It follows that

$${n\over2^n}\int_0^1(1+x^2)^n\,dx=n\int_{1/2}^1{u^n\over\sqrt{2u-1}}\,du=n\int_{1/2}^1u^n\,du+n\int_{1/2}^1u^n\left({1\over\sqrt{2u-1}}-1\right)\,du$$

Now

$$n\int_{1/2}^1u^n\,du={n\over n+1}\left(1-\left(1\over2\right)^{n+1}\right)\to1(1-0)=1$$

So it remains to show that

$$n\int_{1/2}^1u^n\left({1\over\sqrt{2u-1}}-1\right)\,du\to0$$

Note that

$$0\le{1\over\sqrt{2u-1}}-1={1-\sqrt{2u-1}\over\sqrt{2u-1}}={2(1-u)\over\sqrt{2u-1}(1+\sqrt{2u-1})}\le{1-u\over\sqrt{2u-1}}$$

so it's enough to show that

$$n\int_{1/2}^1{u^n(1-u)\over\sqrt{2u-1}}\,du\to0$$

It's convenient to let $u=1-v$ and, taking $n=N^3$ to be sufficiently large, rewrite the integral as

$$\begin{align}
N^3\int_0^{1/2}{v(1-v)^{N^3}\,dv\over\sqrt{1-2v}}
&=N^3\int_0^{1/N^2}{v(1-v)^{N^3}\,dv\over\sqrt{1-2v}}
+N^3\int_{1/N^2}^{1/2}{v(1-v)^{N^3}\,dv\over\sqrt{1-2v}}\\
&\le{N^3\over\sqrt{1-1/N^2}}\int_0^{1/N^2}v\,dv+{N^3\over2}\left(1-{1\over N^2}\right)^{N^3}\int_0^{1/2}{dv\over\sqrt{1-2v}}\\
&={1\over2N\sqrt{1-2/N^2}}+{N^3\over2}\left(\left(1-{1\over N^2}\right)^{N^2} \right)^N\\
&\le{1\over N}+N^3(e^{-1/2})^N\\
&\to0+0=0
\end{align}$$

(Note, these calculations do not require $n$ to be an integer.)

Answer (score 2):

A partial progress

We make the substitution $x\tan(y)$. Then $dx=\sec^2(y)dy$.

Now $$\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2)^ndx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sec^{2n}(y)\sec^2(y)dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sec^{2(n+1)}(y)dy$$

Maybe it will be helpful.

Here is the proof by proceeding in your way.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}>\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n\binom{n}{k}}{2k+2}=\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{n}{2(n+1)}(2^{n+1}-1)$$

Hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n\binom{n}{k}}{2^n(2k+1)}\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{2(n+1)}\left(\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=1$$

Again we see that,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}<1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\right)$$

From this you can show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n\binom{n}{k}}{2^n(2k+1)}\leq1$$

Hence the result will follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write $ \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^ndx = \int_0^1 e^{n\log(1+x^2)}dx $ and use a generalization of Laplace's method to handle the boundary case.